# How to assign an Object Key as an ID value in the Object?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an Javascript object object like the following:

```
    "xx2b": {
        "county": "Baringo",
        "town": "Kabarnet",
        "saccoRegistration": "BO2/08/009",
        "saccoName": "Baringo2"
    },
    "QQDa": {
        "saccoRegistration": "Ba/09/009",
        "town": "Mogotio",
        "county": "Baringo",
        "saccoName": "Baringo1"
    }
}
```

How do I assign the Object Keys also to be values within the objects?

The expected outcome is as illustrated below:

```
{
    "xx2b": {
        "id": "xx2b",
        "county": "Baringo",
        "town": "Kabarnet",
        "saccoRegistration": "BO2/08/009",
        "saccoName": "Baringo2"
    },
    "QQDa": {
        "id":"QQDa",
        "saccoRegistration": "Ba/09/009",
        "town": "Mogotio",
        "county": "Baringo",
        "saccoName": "Baringo1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @steeve and welcome to stackoverflow, as you are new here, I would recommend you to take a look at the [stackoverflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to improve the questions and to avoid any duplications in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach` to iterate the object keys and add a new property to each nested object:

```js
const data = {
    "xx2b": {
        "county": "Baringo",
        "town": "Kabarnet",
        "saccoRegistration": "BO2/08/009",
        "saccoName": "Baringo2"
    },
    "QQDa": {
        "saccoRegistration": "Ba/09/009",
        "town": "Mogotio",
        "county": "Baringo",
        "saccoName": "Baringo1"
    }
}

Object.keys(data).forEach(k => data[k].id = k)

console.log(data)
```